# Given three coordinate points, how do you detect when the angle between them crosses 180 degrees?

Tags: python, math, geometry, trigonometry, angle

This seems like it should be really simple but I'm having trouble with it.  Basically, I have three points that keep changing (lets call them p1, p2, and p3).  Also, let's define p2 as the vertex point.

Essentially, what I need to do is calculate the angle between the three points.  A good example would be if the three angles form a 179 degree angle, then the points change to form a 181 degree angle.  So what I really need is a good method for determining if an angle is greater than 180 degrees.  I tried using the law of cosines, but it did not give me a good answer because when the points form a 181 degree angle, it simply interprets it as a 179 degree angle in a different direction.  Also, I am doing this in Python, if that helps.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a consistent angle measurement scheme? Like are all angles measured ccw?

Comment: In this case you must know that the angle is on the clockwise or counterclockwise side of the first segment, correct? Otherwise interpreting 181 as 179 is absolutely correct.

Comment: All angles are measured consistently.  It doesn't really matter whether its counterclockwise or clockwise, all that matters is when the angle crosses the 180 degree boundary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are trying to decide is whether (p3-p2) is a left or right turn comparing to (p2-p1). This is actually a core part of Graham Scan which is used for computing convex hulls (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham_scan). Quoting Wikipedia with slight edits:

> ...determining whether three points constitute a "left turn" or a
>   "right turn" does not require computing the actual angle between the
>   two line segments, and can actually be achieved with simple arithmetic
>   only. For three points P1=(x1, y1), P2=(x2, y2), and P3=(x3, y3),
>   simply compute the z-coordinate of the cross product of the two
>   vectors (p2-p1) and (p3-p1), which is given by the expression
>   `(x2 - x1) * (y3 - y1) - (y2 - y1) * (x3 - x1)`. If the result is 0, the
>   points are collinear; if it is positive, the three points constitute a
>   "left turn" or counter-clockwise orientation, otherwise a "right turn"
>   or clockwise orientation (for counter-clockwise numbered points).

Comment: This works well.  I would like to add this can also be explained in terms of the wedge product, which doesn't require us to introduce additional dimensions.  The wedge product is also more general, as it works for figuring out the winding in spaces with more dimensions, whereas the cross product only works with 3.

Answer (score 0):

To get signed angle in the full range, use atan2 function with dot and cross product of vectors `p2p1` and `p2p3`

```
Angle(in radians) = atan2(cross(p2p1,p2p3), dot(p2p1,p2p3))
```

Comment: Trigonometry is completely unnecessary here, so I would recommend against the additional complexity.

Comment: @Dietrich Epp Author's phrase `what I need to do is calculate the angle between the three points` means that he needs angle value, not only a fact of 180-border crossing

Comment: The title of the question is "how do you detect when the angle between them crosses 180 degrees?", not "how do you calculate the angle".